# How to unpack deep nested iterable structure

Tags: python, iterable, iterable-unpacking

Say for example I have a structure that contains many sub-elements some of which are structures:

```
v = [1, 2, 3, [4, (5, 6)]]
```

How can I unpack these into a series of names that contain only the contents of the structures and not a structure?

Trying `a, b, c, d, e, f = v` raises a `ValueError` while using the starred expression would assign a structure to the names. How can I unpack them in order to get:

```
print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

to print:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 11):

Assignments are defined recursively, you need to *[use parentheses `()` and/or square brackets `[]` to enclose target names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)* and match the nested structure of your iterable. In your case:

```
a, b, c, (d, (e, f)) = v
print(a, b, c, d, e, f) 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Similarly, with no change in semantics, you could use `[]` to denote the structure:

```
a, b, c, [d, [e, f]] = v
print(a, b, c, d, e, f) 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

or, of course, mix them up.

Python will then unpack `v` and assign the first 3 values normally, then unpack the contents of `(d, (e, f))` and assign `d` and then again unpack `(e, f)` and do the same.

You can see this happening if you import the `dis` module and disassembling the statement with `dis.dis`:

```
dis.dis('a, b, c, (d, (e, f)) = v')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (v)
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          4      # <- first unpack
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
              9 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
             12 STORE_NAME               3 (c)
             15 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2      # <- second unpack
             18 STORE_NAME               4 (d)
             21 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2      # <- third unpack
             24 STORE_NAME               5 (e)
             27 STORE_NAME               6 (f)
             30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             33 RETURN_VALUE
```

In general, to unpack arbitrarily nested structures, match the structure in the left side of the assignment (target-list):

```
v = [1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]]    
[a, [b, [c, [d, e]]]] = v    
print(a, b, c, d, e)
1 2 3 4 5
```

the outer `[]` are, of course, unnecessary, just adding them to show that simply matching the structure suffices.

Answer (score 4):

Another option you might consider is to flatten the structure and then assign it.

```
def flatten(container):
    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, (list,tuple)):
            for j in flatten(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i
```

Then

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = flatten(v)
```

Comment: you could use `isinstance(i, Container)` with `Container` from `collections.abc` in order to catch all containers, not just `list` and `tuple` types.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard: Though you'd likely want to explicitly exclude or otherwise special-case `str` (and possibly `bytes` and related types), since they count as `Container`s but are usually used as if they were scalar quantities.